# Dimension and metrics not appearing properly in data studio community connector

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

Within the getSchema function in my Google Data Studio community connector, I am building up my list of fields and declaring/setting dimensions and metrics accordingly.

ex:

```
fields.newMetric().setId(property.Name).setName(property.Name).setType(keyVal.value).setDescription(property.Description)

fields.newDimension().setId(property.Name).setName(property.Name).setType(keyVal.value).setDescription(property.Description)
```

However, in the connector all fields are displayed as a dimension, and within the report screen it appears to set one field as a dimension and one as a metric.

**My question is how can I get my dimensions and metrics to correctly be displayed within the data studio connector and report?**

Comment: We have this issue too. also when we create a formula field using .setFormula(), the field doesn't have the fx label - it calculate the field right but not work as expected using in a filter, when creating it manually we see it as fx and it work well in a filter.

any idea?

Comment: The metric definition feature still seems to be broken. Do we have any workaround?

Comment: The only work around I have seen is manually dragging fields into metric or dimension once you get to the report screen.